# How to recognize which plugin generated this code?

Tags: plugins

I just took over a website created with wordpress but is broken, the hosting provider reinstalled wordpress but kept the database, so all the information is there, however i can see that the code for the pages seems to have been generated by using some plugin or similar, so now I don't have information of which plugins were installed before but i do have pages that display this kind of code:

```
[section__dd class= 'inhale-top inhale-bottom'][column_dd span='12'][text_dd]
```

does anyone recognize it and knows which plugin was it so i can restore the site or at least see some pages as they were before? I'm usually just in charge of hosting and db management not really familiar with plugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the plugin by running a search for the string "text_dd" in the `wp-content/plugins/` directory.

Looks like this specific plugin (which provides `text_dd`, `column_dd` and `section_dd` shortcodes) is called "dnd-shortcodes" and contains the following snippet of information:

```
Plugin Name: Drag and Drop Shortcodes
Plugin URI: http://themeforest.net/user/AB-themes?ref=AB-themes
Description: Visual drag and drop page builder containing great collection of animated shortcodes with paralax effects and video backgrounds
Version: 1.2.2
Author: Abdev
Author URI: http://themeforest.net/user/AB-themes?ref=AB-themes
```

Answer (score 0):

Plugins add additional functionality to a site. Page code is generated by the theme's templates, which query the database (where content is stored) and display the content with the styling (CSS) and 'structure' (how the content 'pieces' are displayed) as defined by the theme.

The actual theme template used is based on the Theme's Template Hierarchy, which you can learn about here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/getting-started/ .

A good understanding of how themes work to display the content is the first step for you. The link above, along with tons of other information available via the googles, is a starting point.

Comment: No problem, although themes are more than 'just CSS'. The link in my answer is a good start to understanding how themes work in WP to generate pages.